# Module broken by drupal core update (mysql_num_rows)

Tags: 6, database, hooks

So I just updated my Drupal core to the latest (6.2.9) because of the many critical security recommendations.

I have a module which I built and previously, just before the update I had tested the module which uses a hook_cron() function and everything seemed to work as expected.

After the update It seems completely broken, I keep getting a warning "warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource" which I have read a lot about others having the same problem in other threads, couldn't find a solution which worked, but the thing is, it was literally just working for me!!

I ran the `$result` query in a shell and it seems to return the expected data, I don't know what the problem suddenly is. All other modules appear to work normally.

```
function httprequest_cron() {
  $result  = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {httprequest}");
  if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
  // results returned
  $url = 'http://localhost:3000/blog?status=fetch';
  $result = drupal_http_request($url);
  if (isset($result) && in_array($result->code, array('200', '302', '307')) && $result->data != '') {
  db_query("DELETE FROM {httprequest} WHERE nid");
  }
  }
  else {
  // no results, but good query
  }
}
```

Comment: So I ended up getting this working by changing `mysql_num_rows` to `$num_rows = $result->num_rows;` followed by `if ($num_rows >0) {`. All seems to work normally again.

Comment: is this a true copy/paste of your function or did you edit it?  just trying to figure out your `DELETE` query in its present form and the overloading/reuse of the `$result` variable.

Comment: @Jimajamma yes it's a true copy/paste, the delete function seems to work as expected. I realize the $result function is overused but I figure this module is only in use on a small intranet site with minimal users and seems to work as expected with light load

Comment: OK.  I was just worried you were doing something like `WHERE nid = %d` and errantly relying upon `$request` before you reused it.  But if it is working, carry on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `db_affected_rows()` function of the Drupal instead of `mysql_num_rows()` function of mysql to check number of rows result from query.

Your code should be:

```
$result  = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {httprequest}");
    if (db_affected_rows()) {
    //your code
    }
```

Instead of

```
$result  = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {httprequest}");
if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
//your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's something wrong on your first query:

```
db_query("SELECT nid FROM {httprequest}");
```

maybe is returning FALSE.

If you need to check how many rows returns certain query, try to use the Drupal database API.
For example:

```
$result = db_query('SELECT COUNT([table field]) FROM {[database table]}');
  if (db_result($result) > 0) {
      ....
  }
```